# Autofilter Criteria with Array

Tags: arrays, excel, autofilter, vba

I have been looking to find a solution and cant find anything online that fully explains what is going on. I looked at some other posts but they all seem to fall a bit short.

When I run this bit of code it works perfectly (as it was recorded).

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AL$1002").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "73578", "78759", "78765"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

But then when I try to make it more robust it fails. I want to change the Criteria1 argument to an already stored array.

I am trying to get the following to work.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AL$1002").AutoFilter Field:=17, _
    Criteria1:=Array(StoredArray.Values), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

[image: Array values]

I have the array stored and I manipulate it anyway but I have yet to get anything to work. I have also tried to create a string to be exactly like the recorded macro but that does not work either.

```
Dim StoredArrayString as Variant
StoredArrayString = "73578"", ""78759"", ""78765"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AL$1002").AutoFilter Field:=17, _
        Criteria1:=StoredArrayString, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Thanks for the help here I have spent lots of time on MSDN trying to research this issue but can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is with how you're defining your array. Try this instead.

```
Dim StoredArrayString As Variant
StoredArrayString = Array("73578", "78759", "78765")
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AL$1002").AutoFilter Field:=17, _
        Criteria1:=StoredArrayString, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: Sorry if this was unclear. I do NOT want to use this method. I want to use the one that is already defined AKA StartingArray is what I want to use.

Comment: Even if you're not manually creating that array the syntax in the third line should work for you. `Criteria1:=StoredArray` instead of `Criteria1:=Array(StoredArray.Values)` if I still don't understand please go into more detail so we can help.

Comment: I am still having the same issues as I mentioned below. When I use the `Criteria1:=StoredArray` I am getting it to filter but only a filter for the first value in my array. I am suspecting that I might need to redefine the array and it might be due to the size or dimensions. Help on this work be greatly appreciated as I can not figure out why it is doing this. Please see the photo in the original post to see how the variable `StoredArray` is being defined.

Comment: @Ben Okay I think I found your issue. You have a single array but have it set up as a multi dimensional `(1 To 3, 1 To 1)` the `1 To 1` is completely useless here and screwing you up. Could you post the code on where you're pulling that array from or populating it?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with:

[image]

and run:

```
Sub Macro7()
    Dim ary(1 To 3) As String
    ary(1) = "Alice"
    ary(2) = "Boris"
    ary(3) = "James"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$D$22").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=ary, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]

Comment: This is close to working for me the Issue that I am having is that it is only using the first value in my array. See the array that is defined above in the photo.